# Chrome becomes totally unresponsive - Linux Mint

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, linux-mint

Iam running Linux Mint on my laptop and i have some (serious) problems with Google Chrome.
Randomly Chrome becomes totally unresponsive and iam not able to do anything,except restart the system from the power button.
I think it's not an issue with system load and/or RAM,because if i for example open lot of "heavy" programs everything seems to work quite fine.
When i only run Chrome with not many tabs at random times it freezes the whole system.
The weird thing is that Chrome is not heavily loaded with tabs or extensions.
I can't figure out what is causing this problem.
Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved. First, remove Chrome or Chromium and restart your system. Install either Chrome or Chromium and start it but do not try to resize it or move it in any way. Click on the menu at the top right of the window and click on settings. Scroll down to advanced settings near the bottom of the page, turn off "use hardware acceleration".

It will say "restart Chrome". Click where it says' "restart Chrome". This worked for me. My system used to freeze up with Chrome, Chromium and Opera. Now it works great with no issues.

Comment: Hardware acceleration can sometimes be a problem. Uninstalling and reinstalling can fix a lot of problems if they are due to corruption or some other things. You solved your problem with a big hammer and a lot of work. You might have arrived at the same result if you took a more surgical approach.  For example, disable add-ons (although if multiple browsers have a problem, that isn't the likely common denominator). If that doesn't fix it, turn off hardware acceleration. If none of the easy stuff works, then look at reinstalling.  Anyway, glad you solved your problem and thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Chrome Task Manager to see if it's a particular tab, extension or plugin that is struggling. You could also try terminating them one by one to see if you can find the problematic one.

Have you tried using some different browser for a few days to make sure that this is a Chrome problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem, but have found a solution:

Uninstall VLC's plugins for rendering any type of media.

I know VLC is about the best all-around media player, but the plugin is the cause of my iteration of chromium-browser hangs, which it never recovers from.

I hope this helps someone. I have filed this information in a more detailed Google Chrome bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had chromium start locking up after a security update.  It would lock up for 10 yo 20 seconds.  In my case the cure was to turn hardware acceleration back on.  Maybe they should just leave that out of it.